# Not able to display overflown background

Tags: html, css

I have two floated unordered lists that overflow its flex container width. Somehow the background stops at the container's width. Can someone help me stretch that background?

```
.container          { background: #eee; display: flex; flex-direction: column; margin: 0 auto; overflow: auto; width: 700px; }
.large              { background: lightgreen; display: flex; list-style: none; padding: 0; }
.large li           { display: inline-block; margin: 0 10px 0 0; white-space: nowrap; }
```

---

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="large">
        <li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="large">
        <li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zgorr0tr/

Comment: @Paulie_D is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Little change on CSS.

```css
.container   {
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 700px;
}
.large {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.large li {
  background: lightgreen;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="large">
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="large">
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
   <li>item</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: unfortunately that won't work. The background needs to be on the ul element.